# Raid5 gone bad, using ASRock raid

Tags: motherboard, raid, data-recovery

My son has (had) a PC using ASRock Z97 Extreme4 MB. The PC died, seemingly because of some Windows issue. I got the C drive working using Windows restore points &c, and by moving the drives to an almost identical PC with the same motherboard.

The original had 3 1 TB drives in a Raid5 setup, using the BIOS raid settings. The problem is that this MB had different settings, and we likely scrambled the order of the drives when moving them. The new BIOS sees 3 drives, but I cannot see any data on them, just the things shown below.
I do not know what to make of this. We have a spare 1TB disk which I could hook up and move data to, but I do not know which, if any, of the drives are good, or how to move the data - if it still exists.

[image]

Comment: If two drives are bad then the array is toast.  Are the boards running the same exact BIOS version?  If so can you use the old machine to confirm the RAID settings to change on the new one?  Finally is it not possible to swap the drives back to the first board in their original configuration and see if the array works?

Comment: The original Z97 MB will not start.  I gets Dr Debug code 10 immediately.  It starts the CPU fan but does not get beyond that.  I do wish I could put the drives on the original MB, but cannot.

Comment: From what I can find it seems like 10 is a memory error code, you can try reducing /replacing to 1 stick and see if it POSTs.. Regarding the new machine, I don't think SATA order would affect a raid 5, I could be wrong, but pretty sure that if different board revisions have a different RAID implementation then it would certainly have trouble reading the array, and may be impossible to recover